# Proving A dot A x B Using Levi-Civita

Tags: tensor-products

[image]

Is this a valid proof for proving

$\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}  \times  \vec{B} = -\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A} \times \vec{B} $

Comment: you should use that $\hat e_i\cdot\hat e_k=\delta_{ik}$

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\vec A\cdot (\vec A\times\vec B)=\varepsilon_{ijk}A_iA_jB_k=-\varepsilon_{jik}A_iA_jB_k
\end{align}=-\vec A\cdot (\vec A\times \vec B)$$